# Is there a callback that gets fired whenever GCMRegistrar.register(context, sender_id); does it job?

Tags: android, push-notification, registration, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to register for a GCM.

I am first checking if my getRegistrationID returns null, and when it does, I am calling GCMRegistrar.register(context, sender_id).

The thing is, once the registration is done,

```
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)
```

is getting caled which is inside the GCMIntentService class.

Since registration process happens via a seperate asynctask (or any other background process), I know that calling getRegistrationID immediately after this might sometimes return null, as still the registration process could not be over.

I need to use the regId as soon as possible and from my same activitly as I will use them as POST parameters to sent to server.

I am stuck in a condition that the user might click the POST button quickly before the registration is over and I will get a null instead of a value.

How do you tackle this issue ?
(I know a workaround is to issue a message that tells the user to try again after a while).
ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new API - the register method of [GoogleCloudMessaging](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) class. That is the recommended implementation (GCMRegistrar is deprecated). This method is blocking, so you can't call it in the main thread. You can call it in an AsyncTask.

See the new [GCM Demo](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java?r=44e0469692d7d10a104cd689d3045a56971f90ce) for a code sample.